# What if we dont have Quartz Schedulers tables

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz

Need help with a very basic question (actually I am very beginner to Quartz Scheduling just today started learning from https://flylib.com/books/en/2.65.1/ since one of migration project I am working is using this.) 



**Problem statement-**

1) We are using JobStoreCMT with two WebLogic data sources, do we really need Persistent Job Store tables (those basic 12 quartz schedulers tables)?

2) I ran QuartzScheduler but do not see any insertions / updation in JobStore Tables, is something wrong here?

3) Before running Quartz Scheduler Job do we need to do any configuration in quartz persistent job store tables like qrtz_job_details?

4) Any other configurations, if required.

Quick help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also start using the library aproximatelly a month ago, and I suggest you to read the official docs. They are really helpful

1) JobStoreCMT is a implemetation of persistent job store. so the answer is yes, you need quartz tables
From docs http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.3.1-SNAPSHOT/introduction.html

> Transactions
>   Quartz can participate in JTA transactions, via the use
>   of JobStoreCMT (a subclass of JDBCJobStore).

2) If you do not schedule any jobs, there will be no new records. Also you may not configured you quartz scheduller correctly. When initializing, you need for example provide, quartz properties file, with location of you quartz tables.
Docs
http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.3.1-SNAPSHOT/quick-start-guide.html#the-properties-file

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-09.html#TutorialLesson9-JDBCJobStore

Generally, when you start you application, you will have one record with scheduler id in you quartz scheduler table. 
Once you created job with trigger, you will see info in jobs table and in triggers table

3) you shouldn't do anything manually with quart tables, you need to interact with quartz only with scheduler api
Check this lessons to start
http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/tutorials/index.html

4) for basic usage, no additional configuration is required

Comment: The only problem now I am facing is that neither static nor dynamic schedulers are starting when I am using CMTJobStore. quartz.log is also not having any error, I checked WebLogic console for thread dump but no thread is stuck. Also, I have indexes on all quartz table. 
Everything working fine with RAMJobStore. It is related to any parameter in Oracle Database? I have job_queue_processes=10 in database.
<br> I further checked in quartz tables and there is no entry in below tables:
QUARTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS, QUARTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS, QUARTZ_JOB_DETAILS,
QUARTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE, QUARTZ_TRIGGERS

Comment: Also, do we need to insert values in quartz_locks table? Below is property file I am using- 

org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=25
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority=5
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.weblogic.WebLogicOracleDelegate
Please suggest what could be possible cause of the problem that scheduler is not running properly.

Comment: Did you tried to set scheduler factory property autostart to true? Or use scheduler.start()? Also when starting you app, there should be a string in logs with details of quartz scheduler info (parameters, which are used by quartz)

Comment: Actually as a part of migration project we are not allowed to change the code. Is this property you are talking about -
org.quartz.scheduler.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializer = true
      Also I got to know that there is a known problem of quartz Scheduler that it undergoes deadlock when we work with Oracle RAC env. (QTZ-149), do you have any idea on this?